# Context variables not available in django template after first pass through a for loop

Tags: django, for-loop, templates, nested-loops

I am passing a list from a view to a template via a context variable and everything is working fine inside a for loop.  Now I have a requirement that is best satisfied by wrapping the original for loop in an outer loop.  What I've discovered is that the original list disappears after a single pass through the inner loop and is not available to be repeated in subsequent iterations of the parent loop. I'm sure that this is a best practice with regard to memory management but it makes it almost impossible for me to implement the solution I had in mind.  Is there a way to override this behavior so that the lists in the context are preserved in subsequent iterations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I did find a better solution, so this feature of Django prevented me from implementing a bad one. The thing that saved me was the {% ifchanged %} tag, which allowed me to identify when to take the action that I needed to take on the first (and only) pass through the for loop. Cool!